# How to post a WM_KEYUP msg without triggerring a WM_CHAR msg?

Tags: windows, winapi

I have a window, and when I pressed a key, it received a WM_KEYDOWN, a WM_CHAR, and a WM_KEYUP.

I want to simulate a keyboard event, so I use PostMeassage to post a WM_KEYDOWN and a WM_KEYUP to it. But it received WM_CHAR twice.

That is to say, it will receive WM_CHAR whether when it receives WM_KEYDOWN or WM_KEYUP.

To prevent the sencond WM_CHAR message, should I set l/wParam to something?

(I know a kb_event can do it, but I don't want a kb_event.)

Comment: Post code that reproduces this problem.

Comment: I have solved it myself, thank you all the same.

Comment: Just use `PostMessage(hWnd, WM_KEYUP, key, 0xC0000001);`, I used a wrong number as wParam. `PostMessage(hWnd, WM_KEYUP, key, 0xC001);`

Comment: Rather than adding a comment for a problem you solved yourself, you can post your answer and accept it.

Comment: Did you consider using the SendInput API instead of posting system messages?

Comment: @selbie This will only work if the current window has focus. You must use PostMessage if you want to post a message to a window in the background, i.e. a console app.

Comment: @Gravitas - I don't believe that is true if you use KEYEVENTF_SCANCODE in your SendInput call (and use scan codes instead of VK_ flags to inject the keys).  That flag causes SendInput to inject at a lower level into the system that some apps (possibly console apps too) require.